# piwik docker image with nginx on subpath

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, matomo

I have successfully managed to run the `piwiki:fpm` container with docker compose behind nginx using this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  analytics:
    image: piwik:fpm
    volumes:
      - ./config:/var/www/html/config:rw
      - ./logs:/var/www/html/logs
    env_file:
      - ./.matomo-env

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    links:
      - analytics
    volumes_from:
      - analytics
```

and using this nginx coniguration:

```
upstream analytics {
  server analytics:9000;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  root /var/www/html/;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass analytics;
  }
}
```

now this works great when I navigate to `http://localhost/` it will display the piwik interface. Now I wanted to put this in a more complex environment where the root location `/` is not available, so I wanted to use `/analytics`. I've tried may combinations of `location /analytics`, `location ^~ /analytics` but the page never appears, what would be the nginx configuration that would work?

Comment: keep in mind that now that Piwik has been renamed to matomo, the docker image is now also called matomo.

Comment: Did you manage to do that?

Comment: nope, I set it up as a subdomain instead

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for a better solution to my fugly implementation which goes like this:

From my nginx-configuration (from server-block):

```
    location = /matomo/index.php {                                              
        include fastcgi_params;                                                 
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    /var/www/html/index.php;              
        fastcgi_pass my-matomo:9000;                                     
    }                                                                           

    location = /matomo/piwik.php {                                              
        include fastcgi_params;                                                 
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    /var/www/html/piwik.php;              
        fastcgi_pass my-matomo:9000;                                     
    }                                                                           

    location /matomo {                                                          
        alias /var/www/html;                                                    

        try_files $uri @matomo;                                                 
    }                                                                           

    location @matomo {                                                          
        include fastcgi_params;                                                 
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    /var/www/html/index.php;              
        fastcgi_pass my-matomo:9000;                                     
    }
```

Otherwise quite similar to your setup.

Works nicely, but not the tidiest nginx setup ever :)

Comment: Tried but received `client_1   | 2019/04/26 18:10:05 [error] 6#6: *5 no resolver defined to resolve matomo, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /matomo/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
client_1   | 172.18.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2019:18:10:05 +0000] "GET /matomo/index.php HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0" "-"`